Unable to show InterstitialAd in .Net MAUI app
I am using GooglePlayService version 123.6.0 and .net 9. Getting compile time error on OnAdLoaded .OnAdLoaded(): no suitable method found to override. I have tried changing the   GooglePlayService version to 122.0.0 and keep getting the same error
  public class AdMobInterstitialAd
  {
      private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

      public void LoadAd()
      {
          var adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
          InterstitialAd.Load(MainActivity.AppActivity, "Ad Unit ", adRequest, new MyInterstitialAdLoadCallback(this));

          // Create a custom callback to handle ad loading and errors
         
      }
      private class MyInterstitialAdLoadCallback : InterstitialAdLoadCallback
      {
          private readonly AdMobInterstitialAd _adMobInterstitialAd;

          // Constructor to pass reference to outer class
          public MyInterstitialAdLoadCallback(AdMobInterstitialAd adMobInterstitialAd)
          {
              _adMobInterstitialAd = adMobInterstitialAd;
          }
             
          // Override OnAdLoaded method to handle successful ad load
          public override void OnAdLoaded(InterstitialAd ad)
          {
              _adMobInterstitialAd.interstitialAd = ad;
              Console.WriteLine("Ad loaded.");
          }

          // Override OnAdFailedToLoad method to handle ad load failure
          public override void OnAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError error)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Failed to load ad: " + error.Message);
          }
      }
      public void ShowAd()
      {
          if (interstitialAd != null)
          {
              interstitialAd.Show( MainActivity.AppActivity);
          }
          else
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Interstitial ad is not ready.");
          }
      }
  }


As the error states, the OnAdLoaded method, when overridden provides a parameter of type Java.Lang.Object. Similarly, OnAdFailedToLoad provides a parameter of type LoadAdError
It seems you're trying to implement Interstitial Ads in your app and you are expecting the provided parameter of OnAdLoaded method to be of type InterstitialAd.
I would suggest to follow the approach specified in this link to achieve this.
You just have to create a custom callback InterstitialCallback.cs class instead of directly using InterstitialAdLoadCallback to get InterstitialAd as parameter to OnAdLoaded method.
 private class MyInterstitialAdLoadCallback : InterstitialCallback
      {
        
          private readonly AdMobInterstitialAd _adMobInterstitialAd;

          // Constructor to pass reference to outer class
....


I have followed the approach as mentioned in the link and still getting the same errror.

that's impossible if you have implemented it correctly....are you extending InterstitialCallback or still extending InterstitialAdLoadCallback

I still using InterstitialAdLoadCallback as this is expected parameter of Load function. I have crated the MyInterstitialAdLoadCallback custom class derived from InterstitialAdLoadCallback

your MyInterstitialAdLoadCallback should extend newly created call back in the link ... which is InterstitialCallback .. check my updated answer

thanks it's working now. thanks a lot
